# diff: what does this output indicate?

Tags: linux, diff, output

I am using the following command to log the difference between two files on my disk to a log:

```
diff --color=always -sy --suppress-common-lines --suppress-blank-empty file1.c file2.c >> diff_log.txt
```

Inside `diff_log.txt` I see many lines starting with one of the following:

```
^[[31m
^[[0m
```

The `^[` is presented in blue color and `[` in white color.

I am not sure what this implies. Can anyone please explain?

TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange characters in GIT completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181768/strange-characters-in-git-completion)

Comment: @muru not sure...I am not using git...and I am not sure I understand how diff context ties into grep?

Comment: Did you read the question? Both you and OP there are forcing colour output.

Comment: @muru I get the same results even if I were to change --color=auto in my command

Comment: You're appending to the file. Are you sure you're not seeing those from earlier runs of the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are control sequences outputted by the `diff` command to change the color of the text.  It does this because you have requested coloring of the output using `--color=always`.  Consider changing this option to `--color=never` or `--color=auto`, or remove it completely from your command.

Note that if you re-run the command, the new output will be *appended* to the output file since you're using `>>` for the redirection rather than `>` to truncate and rewrite the output file, so you would still see these control sequences in the output file from previous runs.

Another alternative would be to use `less -R` to view the file.  This would interpret the color changing control sequences in the file so that they change the color of the text (see also `man less`).  This would only be an option if you just want to *look* at the file though.  If you want to do further processing of the data, it would be better to instruct `diff` to not produce colorized output.

Related:

- [grep output redirected to file produces binary file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/582322)
- [How do I pipe colored diff output to less?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76224)
- [Strange characters in GIT completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181768)
- [Fail to grep by first character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304200)